# How to do Multirow in one table cell?

Tags: tables, formatting

I tried to do a payoff matrix for game theory, I used the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow,array}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\begin{tabular}{cc|c|c|}
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Player $Y$}\\
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$A$}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$B$} \\\cline{3-4}
  \multirow{2}*{Player $X$}  & $A$ & $(x,y)$ & $(x,y)$ \\\cline{3-4}
  & $B$ & $(x,y)$ & $(x,y)$ \\\cline{3-4}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

And it should have the following outcome: [image]
But I have a problem that my `X` and `y` are really long, I want to put them in different row, like `(x,\\y)`, but it is difficult for me,
I tried Google, they said use:

```
\newcommand{\tabincell}[2]{\begin{tabular}{@{}#1@{}}#2\end{tabular}}
```

But after that, it keeps telling me "missing $ inserted " error, and some letters in "x" and "y" are in text mode rather than math mode even I inserted `$` around them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

for this become package `mathtools` handy:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow}
\setcellgapes{3pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\makegapedcells
\begin{tabular}{cc|c|c|}
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Player $Y$}\\
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$A$}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$B$} \\\cline{3-4}
  \multirow{4}*{Player $X$} & $A$ & $\begin{gathered}(x,\\
                                      y)\end{gathered}$ & $\begin{gathered}(x,\\
                                      y)\end{gathered}$ \\\cline{3-4}
                            & $B$ & $\begin{gathered}(x,\\
                                      y)\end{gathered}$ & $\begin{gathered}(x,\\
                                      y)\end{gathered}$ \\\cline{3-4}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

or use of macro `makecell` from package `makecell`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow}
\setcellgapes{3pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\makegapedcells
\begin{tabular}{cc|c|c|}
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Player $Y$}\\
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$A$}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$B$} \\\cline{3-4}
  \multirow{4}*{Player $X$} & $A$ & \makecell{$(x,$\\
                                              $ y)$} & \makecell{$(x,$\\
                                                                 $ y)$}   \\\cline{3-4}
                            & $A$ & \makecell{$(x,$\\
                                              $ y)$} & \makecell{$(x,$\\
                                                                $ y)$}    \\\cline{3-4}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @JohnZhao, of course they works :). if you liked answer, please up-vote or even accept  it by clicking on up pen and check mark on top left side of answer (this is a habit here to do this instead say "thank you") :-)

Comment: The OP has only 6 rep points, he can't upvote yet. However, he can accept one of our answers. Ciao!

Comment: @CarLaTeX, yeah, i didn't look his reputation ... but he can accept one of our answers :-)

Comment: @Zarko I have already told him to do it :):):)

Comment: Sorry it took me so long, I didn't use this much and weren't familiar with the rules here, I chose your answer and thank you again

Answer (score 1):

Or without any other package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow,array}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$}c<{$}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}

\begin{tabular}{cc|C|C|}
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Player $Y$}\\
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$A$}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$B$} \\\cline{3-4}
  \multirow{4}*{Player $X$}  & \multirow{2}*{$A$} & (x, & (x, \\
    &  & y) & y) \\\cline{3-4}
    & \multirow{2}*{$B$} & (x, & (x, \\
    &  & y) & y) \\\cline{3-4}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @JohnZhao You're welcome! As Zarko told you, choose which is the best answer, according to your needs, and accept it: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1853/101651.